# Picking Frames from a Video saved in my Gallery Android Studio

Tags: java, android, video-capture

I am pretty new to android studio(and java) and i am attempting to make a video processing application. I want the program to upload a video from the users gallery, and then take a picture of the video every second and save it into an array. Logically the code I have written makes sense to me and there are no errors, but when I run the app on my Samsung tablet it crashes after taking the video. I think the setDataSource is unable to find the correct data source, but im not sure how to pass the data from the video along. Can anyone help?

Heres my code:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    savedimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

public void activity(View view) {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), GET_FROM_GALLERY);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    Uri videouri = data.getData();
    retriever.setDataSource(String.valueOf(videouri));
    String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong(time);
    long seconds = timeInmillisec / 1000;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> mylist = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++) {

        Bitmap bArray = retriever.getFrameAtTime(100000 * i, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
        mylist.add(bArray);

    }
}
```

Comment: What the error you are getting when the program crashes? You can get error message from `logcat`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `videouri` is a `Uri`, try calling `void setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri)` instead of `void setDataSource (String path)`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // check for resultCode & requestCode
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GET_FROM_GALLERY) {

            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            Uri videouri = data.getData();

            // "videouri" is Uri, call setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri) instead
            retriever.setDataSource(this, videouri);

            .....

    }
}
```